# Sorting on last record of a has many relationship table rails and retaining main table values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have a `tickets` table which `has_many ticket_messages`. I need to sort on the created at of the last ticket_message. I did that using:

```
Ticket.joins(:ticket_messages).where('ticket_messages.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ticket_messages.created_at) FROM ticket_messages WHERE ticket_messages.ticket_id = tickets.id)').order("ticket_messages.created_at #{asc_or_desc}")
```

This filters out tickets which have no `ticket_messages`. I want to retain the `tickets` as well and display them. How do I do this?

I tried this:

```
Ticket.includes(:ticket_messages).order("MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)")
```

Throws an error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ticket_messages"
LINE 1: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets"   ORDER BY MAX(ticket_mess...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets"   ORDER BY MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ticket_messages"
LINE 1: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets"   ORDER BY MAX(ticket_mess...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets"   ORDER BY MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)>
```

I have also tried this:

```
Ticket.joins(:ticket_messages).order("MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)")
```

This also throws an error:

```
    Ticket Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "ticket_messages" ON "ticket_messages"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id"  ORDER BY MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "tickets.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "ticket_message...
               ^
: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "ticket_messages" ON "ticket_messages"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id"  ORDER BY MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "tickets.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "ticket_message...
               ^
: SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "ticket_messages" ON "ticket_messages"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id"  ORDER BY MAX(ticket_messages.created_at)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asc` or `desc` to sort it in ascending or descending order respectively

```
Ticket.includes(:ticket_messages).order("ticket_messages.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: MAX() gives the last `ticket_messages` back. It is not for DESC or ASC.

Comment: What do you mean by last ticket messages, can you explain?

Comment: ticket has_many ticket_messages. I want to order the tickets on last created ticket_message.